# How to remove Parameters and Filters in a T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I created a sql trace and my task is build a report listing the 10's most used commmands.
My problem is: I have the same procedure 100 times but my problem is it is using different filter and parameters. I need to remove them for using count functions (pe, 100 occurrences of this procedure is, true of fact, just one for my report).

There is any program or TSQL code for this removal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**ClearTrace**](http://www.scalesql.com/cleartrace/) will do the thing you need. Its free to download as well.

> Normalized SQL Statements
>   ClearTrace "normalizes" the SQL statements to eliminate transient differences in SQL statements.  For example, the following statement
>
> Select * From qryLinksByNewsletterID Where NewsletterID=19
>
> is normalized to
>
> SELECT * FROM QRYLINKSBYNEWSLETTERID WHERE NEWSLETTERID={##}

Comment: Only if your trace has these events: SQL:BatchCompleted and RPC:Completed. It ignores anything else.